# How to serve static files in ExpressJS when you are routing a deep directory path?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, static-files

I guess the title might be confusing. I didn't know how to word it but say i have a directory as follows:

```
/
   app.js
   /static
      /styles
         main.css
   /views
      index.html
      /files
         1.html
         2.html
```

If I serve 1.html and have in it, i have a css file as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/styles/main.css">
```

This does not load the css file. It works fine on the index page I'm assuming because it is directly inside the views folder. Because I'm trying to access something in the files folder, its not working. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Also note I have set

```
server.set('views', __dirname + '/views')

server.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
```

Comment: For resources in a fixed position, use absolute paths (paths that start with `/`) to reference them in the web page.  Then you can reach them the same way no matter where the host web page is served from.  So, since you are using `express.static(__dirname + '/static')` already, then just use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/main.css">`./  The `/static` part is already in your `express.static()` handler.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `static` from href attribute

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/main.css">
```

And change the static files serving configuration to

```
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));
```